# WPF DataGrid adding new row setting focus first cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus

WPF DataGrid while adding new row focus is always setting to last position of cell.

How would I can set to the first cell's focus while adding new row?

1.I have simple 6 columns so when I press enter on last column it should add new row (working fine)
2.Focus should be the added row's first cell it won't happen it is always in the last cell

I am attaching my WPF Sample demo as well please correct me where I am wrong?
Demo Link: [WPFDemo](https://github.com/jitendrajadav/WPFDEMO)

Thank you,
Jitendra Jadav.

Comment: Letting the user work with a datagrid to enter data like it was excel is usually something to be avoided. Validation is a particular nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle previewkeydown on the datagrid:

```
private void dg_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var el = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && el != null)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        el.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
}
```

The markup is probably obvious but:

```
    <DataGrid Name="dg"
              ...
              PreviewKeyDown="dg_PreviewKeyDown"
```

There may well be some unexpected side effects, I just tested you hit enter in the last cell and you end up in the first cell of the next row OK.

Comment: Thank you @Andy but unfortunately your suggestion not working

Comment: My suggestion definitely works if there's any data presented to the datagrid. I'm afraid I don't really want to download and delve into your app here.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `CellEditEnding` event and get a reference to the `DataGridCell` as explained in the following blog post.

**How to programmatically select and focus a row or cell in a DataGrid in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/

This seems to work for me:

```
private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder) as DataGridRow;
    if (row != null)
    {
        dataGrid.SelectedItem = row.DataContext;
        DataGridCell cell = GetCell(dataGrid, row, 0);
        if (cell != null)
            dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
    }
}

private static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridRow rowContainer, int column)
{
    if (rowContainer != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
        if (presenter != null)
            return presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
    }
    return null;
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
            return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you suggestion it work but only one problem is there while pressing enter of 1st cell it is adding new row I want to add new row while pressing enter of last cell. could please correct it or provide me some guide on it that could be great help

Comment: That's a totally different question. Your original question was "How would I set to the first cell's focus while adding new row?" and I believe this one has been answered. Please ask a new question if you have another issue. I would be glad to try to help you if I can. But please don't ask additional questions in the comments field.

Comment: Hi @mm8, that is right but if you look at point I have mention my requirement please check it if you want another question fine then I will post new question please let me know. thank you

Comment: As mentioned, your original question was how to focus the first cell when adding a new row. Once again, please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code, select first cell and fix tab focuse out of datagride:

```
private void table_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var el = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter && el != null)
            {
                table.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(table.Items[table.Items.Count-1], table.Columns[0]);
                table.SelectedCells.Clear();
                table.SelectedCells.Add(table.CurrentCell);
            }else if (e.Key == Key.Tab && el != null && table.SelectedCells[0].Column.DisplayIndex > table.Items.Count)
            {
                table.Focus();
            }
        }
```