# How to set the cursor on the first cell of an empty row in datagrid which is bound to a data table

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid, text-cursor

I have a datagrid which is bound to a datatable. I would like to know - How can we show the Cursor as blinking in the first cell of an empty row of this datagrid which is bound to the datatable. Also, when a user adds a new empty row to this datatable/datagrid by hitting the enter key, The cursor should blink on the first cell of the new added empty row.

Here's the UI that's shown at the moment, but the user may not know where to insert a value since there's no cursor blinking on the last empty row.

[image]

Here's the code:

View.xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"                           
                          Height="400"
                          Width="Auto"
                          SelectionMode="Single"                        
                          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                          GridLinesVisibility ="Vertical"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                          CanUserResizeRows="False"                
                          BorderThickness="0" 
                          CanUserAddRows="True" 
                          RowHeaderWidth="0">                                                  
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
private DataTable _MyDataTable;

public DataTable MyDataTable
{
    get { return _MyDataTable; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _MyDataTable, value); }
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using a datagrid for data entry purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997387/wpf-datagrid-adding-new-row-setting-focus-first-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997387/wpf-datagrid-adding-new-row-setting-focus-first-cell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're refering to as "setting the blinking cursor" is known as focusing (when a text box is focused it will show the blinking caret; when a button is focused the Enter key will trigger it's click etc.)

Here's a detailed article with multiple examples of how to focus rows/cells in a datagrid: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21202.wpf-programmatically-selecting-and-focusing-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid.aspx